# Codes regarding RStudio

Tags: r

Would anyone explain the two lines of code here? All I know is that it is about finding the quantiles. The codes were taken from a website for reference purposes:

```
quant <- function(x) {quantile(x,probs=0:10/10)}
apply(new.df[,1:dim(new.df)[2]],2,quant)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Function `quant` calculates [deciles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decile) of the vector passed as an argument. Expression `1:dim(new.df)[2]` returns a vector starting from `1` and ending with the number equal to the amount of columns. `new.df[, 1:dim(new.df)[2]]` chooses all the columns in `new.df` (however it is strange and no direct sense as it is identical just to `new.df` itself). Function `apply` with the second argument `2` takes columns one-by-one and call the function `quant`. For example:

```
new.df <- structure(list(a = c(36, 12, 14, 4, 3, 8, 4, 7), b = c(6, 12, 
3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7), c = c(36, 7, 6, 4, 9, 8, 4, 7), d = c(6, 12, 
12, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7), e = c(36, 6, 3, 6, 4, 9, 4, 7), f = c(36, 
5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 8, 7), g = c(36, 12, 12, 14, 4, 6, 4, 7), h = c(6, 
6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
# new.df dataframe:
#   a  b  c  d  e  f  g h
# 1 36  6 36  6 36 36 36 6
# 2 12 12  7 12  6  5 12 6
# 3 14  3  6 12  3  4 12 3
# 4  4  4  4  5  6  6 14 4
# 5  3  6  9  4  4  6  4 6
# 6  8  4  8  7  9  3  6 8
# 7  4  8  4  8  4  8  4 4
# 8  7  7  7  7  7  7  7 7
quant <- function(x) {
  quantile(x, probs = 0:10 / 10)
}

apply(new.df[, 1:dim(new.df)[2]], 2, quant)
```

Returns as the result:

```
        a    b    c    d    e    f    g   h
0%    3.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  4.0 3.0
10%   3.7  3.7  4.0  4.7  3.7  3.7  4.0 3.7
20%   4.0  4.0  4.8  5.4  4.0  4.4  4.8 4.0
30%   4.3  4.2  6.1  6.1  4.2  5.1  6.1 4.2
40%   6.4  5.6  6.8  6.8  5.6  5.8  6.8 5.6
50%   7.5  6.0  7.0  7.0  6.0  6.0  9.5 6.0
60%   8.8  6.2  7.2  7.2  6.2  6.2 12.0 6.0
70%  11.6  6.9  7.9  7.9  6.9  6.9 12.0 6.0
80%  13.2  7.6  8.6 10.4  8.2  7.6 13.2 6.6
90%  20.6  9.2 17.1 12.0 17.1 16.4 20.6 7.3
100% 36.0 12.0 36.0 12.0 36.0 36.0 36.0 8.0
```